# How to re-install OS X from single-user mode

Tags: install, driver, gpu, single-user

So, this mac had some graphics card drivers that were potentially corrupt. After moving them out of the drivers folder, I'm able to boot in normally. However recovery boot isn't working, I can't get it to update via the App Store, I can't open Finder, nor can I do a myriad of other things. I need to re-install the OS, but can't seem to find any way of doing it... my only thought is that I could re-install it via single-user mode which is the only thing that seems to be working perfectly fine.

**How do I re-install my OS from single-user mode?**

<sub>EDIT: Well, I found out why it wasn't booting into recovery boot: the graphics card drivers for the main system weren't working - for the same reason the drivers in the recovery partition were not working, both on the computer's harddisk, and on the recovery usb I made. After disabling (moving) the drivers on the usb, it booted to it fine. The issue is the graphics card hardware.</sub>

<sub>Nonetheless, I'll leave this question here since it's still a great question that deserves a good answer.</sub>

Comment: What version of osx is it?

Comment: Did you already try to boot to Internet Recovery Mode (alt-cmd-R while booting)? Mac OS X ≥ 10.7 - DHCP/DNS obligatory - Ethernet recommended.

Comment: It's OS X Lion (10.7.5) currently, but I'm attempting to upgrade it to Mountain Lion or Yosemite, both of which I have the installers for. But due to its lack of drivers, I can't even run any installers.